# New function declaration inline in a java subclass

Tags: java

I have a class called "Design", and I am writing the following code to extend the class to include a new function called sayHello(). However it doesnt seem to be working. Am I only allowed to ovveride existing functions in that way?

```
Design design1 = new Design() {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
};

design1.sayHello();  // this gives an error "function not found"
```

Comment: The actual type of your variable has the `sayHello` method; but it's an anonymous type, and your variable is of type `Design` which doesn't have the method. If you want to call the new method, you'll need to formally declare the type before instantiating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that is logical. 
You are overriding a super class and assigning it to the instance variable of super class.

As the instance variable is of super class type, you can access only those methods which are available in super class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if your "Design" class is an interface. You could create an anonymous inner class.

Example:

```
public interface Design{
     public void sayHello();
}

public class Test
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
             Design d = new Design(){
                 @Override
                 public void sayHello(){
                       return "Hello World!";
                 }
             };
           System.out.println(d.sayHello());      
     }
}
```